# No suitable driver for H2 Database

Tags: scala, playframework

I am following the Play tutorial from http://semisafe.com/coding/2015/06/12/play_basics_database_access.html, specifically the "DEFINING A SCHEMA WITH EVOLUTIONS" part, which shows the usage of H2.

As intructed there, I added `"com.h2database" % "h2" % "1.4.191"` to my `build.sbt` and removed the `jdbc` dependency.

Then, I added up and down actions for database tables in the file `conf/evolutions/default/1.sql`.

Then I added this to `conf/application.conf`:

```
slick.dbs.default.driver="slick.driver.H2Driver$"
slick.dbs.default.db.driver="org.h2.Driver"
slick.dbs.default.db.url="jdbc:h2:./db/overlord;MODE=MYSQL"
slick.dbs.default.db.user=sa
slick.dbs.default.db.password=""
```

After running the evolutions, I started the activator and typed `h2-browser` to see H2 in the browser.

However, in the browser, when I am passing it the database URL, I am getting:

No suitable driver found for `ticket-overlords/db/overlord 08001/0`, where `ticket-overlords` is the name of my project.

Why is this happening?

Comment: What version of Play are you using?

Comment: Have you tried **not** removing the `jdbc` dependency?

Comment: It throws an error saying the DB API was alredy configured: 
`CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:

1) A binding to play.api.db.DBApi was already configured at play.api.db.slick.evolutions.EvolutionsModule.bindings(EvolutionsModule.scala:14):`

Comment: play 2.5.0? it was released very recently, drivers may not be prepared for that. have you tried 2.4.6?

Comment: @octavian , did you get any luck with this. facing the same issue